# Can I hook up a subpanel to an existing 220 line that isn't in use?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

When our house was built, they put a 220 line in for future pool equipment. The pool equipment ended up going on the other side of the house, so this line just terminates in a box unused. I want to hook up a sub panel off this line to run a few circuits for a couple things in the backyard - outdoor lighting, sprinklers, and lights/fans/receptacles for our outdoor kitchen. The 220 line is 8/3 with ground, coming off 2 bridged 50 amp breakers in the main. I'm looking at a 125amp panel with 6 spaces (I know more spaces is always better, but I currently plan on using only 2 or 3 spaces,  so I'll have a few open spots if I come up with any future needs for a circuit). Can I simply hook up this 220 line to a sub panel?

Comment: What type of 8/3 cable are we talking about here? NM/Romex? UF (grey/outdoor romex)? Or some metal-armored cable (AC or MC)?

Comment: Is the box where the line terminates on or in the house? IE: the same structure that your main panel is in?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could go with your plan but most of us will strongly suggest a larger panel. As it is for outside circuits everything will require GFCI protection. If the box or panel location is outside the panel will need to be rated 3R (for outdoor use). 
But yes you can do as you have planned. 
If the panel is not located on the house an additional grounding electrode will be needed.